# Python __repr__ for numbers?

Tags: python

I have the following (example) code:

```
class _1DCoord():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def pixels(self):
        return self.i

    def tiles(self):
        return self.i/TILE_WIDTH
```

What I want to do is this:

```
>>> xcoord = _1DCoord(42)
>>> print xcoord 
42
```

But instead I see this:

```
>>> xcoord = _1DCoord(42)
>>> print xcoord
<_1DCoord instance at 0x1e78b00>
```

I tried using __repr__ as follows:

```
def __repr__(self): 
    return self.i
```

But __repr__ can only return a string.
Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do, or should I just give up and use pixels()?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def __repr__(self): 
  return repr(self.i)
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks a ton! I also had to define \_\_add\_\_, \_\_sub\_\_ etc. so that I could work with the returned value (it was giving me type errors), but that works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
class _1DCoord():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __repr__(self):
        return '_1DCoord(%i)' % self.i

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.i)

>>> xcoord = _1DCoord(42)
>>> xcoord
_1DCoord(42)
>>> print xcoord
42
```

Answer (score 5):

> But `__repr__` can only return a string.

So just do

```
def __repr__(self): 
    return str(self.i) # or repr(self.i)
```

Or, to mimic the usual Python format:

```
def __repr__(self): 
    return '_1DCoord(%i)' % self.i
```

Answer (score 1):

The **repr** method allows you to define your own string representation of a class instance. It must take only self as a parameter and return a string. Ideally, the **repr** method should return the information required to build a copy of the instance.To use the **repr** method do something like:

`def __repr__(self):`

`return f"{self.instance}"`

This allows you to return a string representation of your attribute because **repr** is an inbuilt method in python classes.